# Jenkins scripted pipleline @NonCPS and StackOverflowError

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cps

I have the simple pipeline script:

```
#!groovy

@org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.Library('Some@lib')

import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS

node() {

    echo CheekyEnum.getByName('name1').getName()

}

enum CheekyEnum {

    ENUM_1('name1', 'f1'),
    ENUM_2('name2', 'f2')

    String name
    String field

    CheekyEnum(String name, String field) {
        this.name = name
        this.field = field
    }

    static CheekyEnum getByName(String name) {
        return values().find { it.name == name }
    }
    
    String getName() {
        return name
    }
}
```

When I run it everything works OK, but if there is a little change in method `getName()`

```
@NonCPS
String getName() {
    return name
}
```

I get a pretty long error stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:398)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxResolvingClassLoader.lambda$loadClass$0(SandboxResolvingClassLoader.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxResolvingClassLoader.lambda$load$2(SandboxResolvingClassLoader.java:85)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2337)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1892)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2335)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2318)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:111)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalManualCache.get(LocalManualCache.java:54)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxResolvingClassLoader.load(SandboxResolvingClassLoader.java:79)
    ...
```

Why? Doesn't `@NonCPS` just make method excluded from CPS transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enum is *per se* a serializable type. So you should better create a wrapper function for it:

```
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS

node() {

    echo getName(CheekyEnum.getByName('name1'))

}
...
@NonCPS
String getName(CheekyEnum cheeky) {
    return cheeky.name
}
```

The related StackOverflowError *could* be a bug/smell in the [workflow-cps-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin). Please take a look at its [Technical design](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/README.md)

> Pipeline scripts may mark designated methods with the annotation @NonCPS. These are then compiled normally (except for sandbox security checks).

AFAICS you're running inside a Groovy sandbox. The SandboxInterceptor
is probably generating this stack overflow. Running outside the sandbox should fix your issue as well.

BTW you can also read [Pipeline CPS Method Mismatches](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/) for a better understanding of what can be called in non-CPS transformed code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Enum is serializable, ok then, isn't it mean that we shouldn't have any problem with CPS? Why do I need wrapper?

Comment: @RedMurloc You annotated the method with `NonCPS`, so that is why a serializable type would cause a problem.